# Js- How to check if all keys in object array === false?

Tags: javascript

I want to check my array object to see if all the **keys equal to false**.

```
const response = [
  {
   "add": false,
   "edit": false
  },
  {
   "delete": false
  }
];


if (allKeys === false) {

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check that every object in the array has all the values as `false`.

If there's ever anything that isn't `false`, it'll break out and return `false` without evaluating everything else in the array & current object's keys

```js
const response = [{
    "add": false,
    "edit": false
  },
  {
    "delete": false
  }
];

const response2 = [{
    "add": false,
    "edit": false
  },
  {
    "delete": true
  }
];

const allFalse = (arr) => {
  return arr.every(
    (obj) => Object.values(obj).every((value) => value === false)
  )
}

console.log(allFalse(response));
console.log(allFalse(response2));
```

Answer (score -1):

This method will just gather the object values through a flatMap and test for any true value

```js
const response = [
  {
   "add": false,
   "edit": false
  },
  {
   "delete": false
  }
];

let allFalse = !response.flatMap(Object.values).includes(true)
console.log(allFalse)
```

Comment: This would only work if all the keys are defined booleans. Might work for OP's usecase, but not in general looking for "all the keys equal to false"

Comment: sure but it directly answers OP's concern. Likewise your function would not catch a falsey value, just a false one, so I'm not sure why you point this out